# WooCommerce product thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, thumbnails

I’m having a problem with my cart page. The problem I’m having is the product thumbnail image is cropped and is cutting off my image.

I went to the product display settings and adjust the thumbnail size and the thumbnail image is still too small and cropped.

[cart page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1uWy.png)

I want to figure out how to fix this issue, can someone help?

I also want to find out how can I change the product image on the cart page to a different picture and it not effect the product images on front-end of my site.

Answer (score 0):

Because we don't have a code here I just can figure out what it could be. You can try to set this css to the product image:

```css
.your-product-image { /*PLEASE UPDATE*/
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ItsOdi1 I resolved that issue (in a different method).

I'm still having a problem with just changing the cart image just for that page and it not affecting the other product images on the website.